# Powershell Foreach loop to iterate through API output and display variable values line by line

Tags: powershell, rest, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I am running some Azure DevOps API queries in Postman which successfully return the expected results, a snippet of which is shared below and represents only one of dozens of similar iterative output. For the purpose of this illustration,let us assume the snippet below of Id value 66, is only one of 100s.

```
        "id": 66,
        "buildNumber": "20210401.7",
        "status": "completed",
        "result": "succeeded",
        "queueTime": "2021-04-01T16:50:04.9218848Z",
        "startTime": "2021-04-01T16:50:15.3583291Z",
        "finishTime": "2021-04-01T16:50:53.7221605Z",
```

I am now looking to iteratively parse the 100+ records with a Powershell foreach loop, piping out the "id","buildNumber", "status" and "result" values line by line into an output file.

The desired output should look something like the below:

```
        "id": 66,
        "buildNumber": "20210401.7",
        "status": "completed",
        "result": "succeeded",

        "id": 65,
        "buildNumber": "20210331.5",
        "status": "completed",
        "result": "failed",

        "id": 64,
        "buildNumber": "20210331.4",
        "status": "completed",
        "result": "succeeded",
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve this would be most appreciated.

***[[MY CURRENT POWERSHELL SCRIPT WITH PERSONAL VARIABLES EDITED OUT]]***

Clear-Host
$connectionToken="[MY-PAT]"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$url = 'https://dev.azure.com/[MY-AZURE-ORG]/[MY-TEAM-PROJECT]/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0'

$PackageInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

$LatestVersion= $PackageInfo.value.buildnumber | Select-Object -first 1

$BuildResult= $PackageInfo.value.result | Select-Object -first 1

foreach ($item in $PackageInfo)
{
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Latest build = $LatestVersion" "|" "Build Result = $BuildResult"
Write-Host " "
}

***[[OUTPUT FROM ABOVE SCRIPT]]***

[image]

As can be seen from the above image, by retrieving the last build record, I get the above output returned by my Powershell script, which is great.

I am however not after only the last build record. I want all the build records listed line by line. Therefore, any refinement of my existing script to achieve this will ideally be what would be most suitable as it only requires a minor tweak in my opinion.

Omitting the Select-Object returns all of the expected data, but in the below format which isn't displayed in my preferred format of individual rows.

[image]

Comment: Try `foreach ($build in  $PackageInfo.value) { 'Build: {0} | Result: {1}' -f $_.buildnumber, $_.result }`

Comment: @Theo, I gave your suggestion a go by replacing my foreach loop with yours but I'm afraid yours results in no build data values being returned. What I am getting though are the Build: and Result: labels for each record being displayed line by line, which is great, but not quite the complete solution. Now just need to get the respective data values displayed in the output..

Comment: @Theo, would be much appreciated if you were able to illustrate in the relevant section of my original script (above), where I can insert your proposed changes to ensure I get the build number and build result displayed as expected.

Comment: Sorry, my earlier comment had a mistake.. Instead of your `foreach` loop try `foreach ($build in  $PackageInfo.value) { 'Build: {0} | Result: {1}' -f $build.buildnumber, $build.result }` or do `$PackageInfo.value | ForEach-Object { 'Build: {0} | Result: {1}' -f $_.buildnumber, $_.result }`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting info for builds so I am assuming you are using below Azure DevOps API :

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0)

Using PowerShell, firstly you will need to authenticate ,
You can use OAuth2 Authentication :
Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops

PAT access method can be used but token needs to be manually generated from UI.

```
function getBearer([string]$TenantID, [string]$ClientID, [string]$ClientSecret)
{
  $TokenEndpoint = {https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/token} -f $TenantID 
  $ARMResource = "https://management.core.windows.net/";

  $Body = @{
          'resource'= $ARMResource
          'client_id' = $ClientID
          'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
          'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
  }

  $params = @{
      ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      Headers = @{'accept'='application/json'}
      Body = $Body
      Method = 'Post'
      URI = $TokenEndpoint
  }

  $token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

  Return "Bearer " + ($token.access_token).ToString()
}


    $header = @{
Authorization = getBearer $TenantId $ClientId $ClientSecret
content-type = 'application/json'
}

$ApiUri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0"

$data = (Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $ApiUri -Method Get -Headers $header).value

$OutputFile = "<file-name>"

Class BuildObject {
    id [String]
    buildNumber [String]
    status [String]
    result [String]
}
$BuildObj = New-Object $BuildObject


foreach($buildItem in $data) {
    $BuildObj.id = $buildItem.id
    $BuildObj.buildNumber = $buildItem.buildNumber
    $BuildObj.status = $buildItem.status
    $BuildObj.result = $buildItem.result
    
    $BuildObj | OutFile -FilePath $OutputFile -Append
}
```

Comment: I have tried to run your script and unfortunately run into some errors, a screenshot of which I'll share below.

Comment: I have tried to run your script and unfortunately run into some errors, a screenshot of which I'll share below.

Having said all that and in light of the error encountered, I personally think your script might be a bit of an overkill, as I have a much more simplified one which I was looking to slightly modify to achieve the desired result. Again, I'll share this (my apologies, I should have perhaps done so earlier) by appending it to my original question, as I am sure it adds more context and can then be useful to others in future. Will welcome your feedback on how to refine that script.

Comment: [[SCRIPT ERROR SCREENDUMP]]

At line:29 char:8
+ content-type = 'application/json'
+        ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:38 char:6
+ Class BuildObject {
+      ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:38 char:6
+ Class BuildObject {
+      ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral

Answer (score 0):

```
$datepoint = "MAIN_20230601"
$accountingTypesArray = "AccruedExternalInterest","AccruedInternalInterest","AccruedFee"

foreach ($item in $accountingTypesArray)
{
    $finalUrl = "https://encx-eodd-test.net/api/Delivery/Trigger?accountingPoint="+$datepoint+"&productSystem=WSO&accountingType="+$item
   
 $response = Invoke-RestMethod $finalUrl -Method 'GET' 
    Write-Output $response.slideshow
}
```

Comment: Calling API using Powershell using For loop